# Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False | help needed?

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection

I've looked at some others with the same error but their solution doesn't help me.

> `Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` Error 1004

Here is my code

```
'
' LoadData Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;Macintosh HD:Users:Karrar:Desktop:Excel.txt", Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Excel"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .UseListObject = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Comment: I tried that but instead I got error 438 this time, thnx.

Comment: I get it when I add     ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False "Run time error '438'"

Comment: where do I type the code you said     ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: Try to use it like this                                                                                                          ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub