# Run Time error '1004:, General ODBC ERROR

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script which is not running on my system. I am not expert in this and the person who made script is no more with the organisation anymore.

Any assistance on this will be appreciated.

After Doing Debug, the highlighted filed is "`.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`"

Below is the script: -

```
        Sub Run_Customs_Report()
        '
        ' Macro4 Macro
        '

        '
        Sheets("Customs_Report").Select
            With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
                "ODBC;DSN=GOMS_MEM;UID=OD173;PWD=Adbu765$;DBQ=MDCGOMP.WORLD;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM" _
                ), Array( _
                "=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;STE=F;TSZ=8192;" _
                )), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
                .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT TO_CHAR (D.PRINT_PART_NO) AS ""Print Part"",A.CATALOG_DESC AS ""Descripcion"",B.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN AS ""Country"",B" _
                , _
                ".Packing_list_no AS ""Packing List"",TO_CHAR (A.order_no) AS ""Order"", A.Customer_PO_NO AS ""PO"", ROUND(A.Unit_Price) AS ""Unit" _
                , _
                " Price"", SUM (B.QTY_SHIPPED) AS ""Qty"", ROUND(SUM (A.unit_Price * B.QTY_SHIPPED)) AS ""Ext Total"", TO_CHAR (B.INVOICE_NO) AS" _
                , _
                " ""Manifest"", TO_CHAR(B.INVOICE_DATE) AS ""Date"", C.note_text AS ""GOMS Ref"", TO_CHAR (B.TRACKING_NO) AS ""Tracking No"", TO_CHAR" _
                , _
                " (A.SHIP_TO_ABBR) AS ""Ship To Location"" FROM oeorder_detail A INNER JOIN oeorder_shipping B ON A.part_no = B.part_n" _
                , _
                "o AND A.order_no = B.order_no AND A.line_no = B.line_no INNER JOIN OECUSTOMER_ORDER_NOTES C ON A.order_no = C.order" _
                , _
                "_no INNER JOIN PART_DESCRIPTION D ON A.part_no = D.part_no AND A.SHIP_TO_ABBR IN ('54827','54734','55945','56169','" _
                , _
                "55897','56086') AND (TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (INVOICE_DATE)) = '1' AND B.tracking_no IS NOT NULL AND note_no = '1' " _
                , _
                "AND LINE_NO is null GROUP BY D.PRINT_PART_NO,A.CATALOG_DESC,B.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN,B.Packing_list_no,A.order_no," _
                , _
                "Customer_PO_NO,A.Unit_Price,B.INVOICE_NO,B.INVOICE_DATE,C.note_text, B.TRACKING_NO, A.SHIP_TO_ABBR ORDER BY A.Ship_" _
                , "To_Abbr, B.INVOICE_NO")
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = True
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_1"
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery = False

end with

    end sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False | help needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428059/refresh-backgroundquery-false-help-needed)

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by the *.Refresh* line because it's that line which triggers the execution of the SQL query.

Whilst I find the use of *Array()* a bit strange, if nothing has changed in the code, I would check with your database administrator whether the user account **OD173** is still active.